# Can you use SQL to query the Select/Omit criteria of an AS/400 logical file?

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

I need to be able to lookup the Select/Omit critera of an AS/400 Logical File using SQL.  I cannot use DSPSELOMT.

I figured out how to query whether or not the Logical File has Select/Omit critera by looking at the SELECT_OMIT column in SYSTABLES. ([IBM i catalog tables and views](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzcatalogtbls.htm))

However, I cannot figure out how to query the criteria used in the Select/Omit statement.  How can you view the Select/Omit critera using SQL?  If it's not possible, could you cite a source?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like a utility.  Have the IBM i programmers write you a stored procedure that you can call.  If that doesn't work for you, what is the business problem?  Perhaps there is another way to get at the answer you need.

Comment: There is no system table for that because the Select/Omit feature of LFs is not a SQL feature. SQL has no concept of the Select/Omit feature. The column in SYSTABLES is primarily used simply to determine if any index in that LF is acceptable to the query optimizer. It doesn't need to know the definition, but only the fact that the feature is used in that file.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional method would be to use the `DSPFD` command, with `TYPE(*SELECT) FILEATR(*LF) OUTPUT(*OUTFILE)`.  You can then use SQL to read the select omit criteria from your output file.  If you cannot directly execute the CL command, you might put it inside a stored procedure or user defined function.  Other options to execute the command may be available depending upon what environment your process is running in.

Comment: I do not have access to that command.  I was hoping for some built-in system table which is dynamically updated.

Comment: What type(s) of access are you able to use?